# React handler - currying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi can anyone explain me how this currying works in example below?

The **name** argument I could understand but the event? How is it done?

```
 <TextField
          placeholder="Name"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          className={classes.textfield}
          value={name}
          onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
 />

 handleChange = name => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
 });
};
```

Greetings

Comment: This might help https://gist.github.com/amitai10/adb66d6faa714e8c3cdb94946bb98356

Comment: Well the `event` is passed when the `onChange` handler is called by the `TextField` component.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the below code

```
handleChange = name => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
 });
```

as

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

 handleChange(name){
   return (event) => {
      this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value,
       });
   }
}
```

so basically calling handleChange like `this.handleChange('name')` will return the function to `onChange` event. The onChange when triggered will call this method with the `event` argument. Now that the returned function forms a closure with the outer handleChange function it can use the `name` variable from its enclosing scope, which is how the above code with currying will work

Answer (score 2):

A function called by an event handler will be passed an `Event` object as argument. Imagine the `addEventListener` method implemented by browsers looks like this:

```
something.addEventListener = (eventName, callback, useCapture) => {
  // Some code here
  // Bla bla bla
  const eventObj = {
    // Event object
  };
 callback(eventObj);
}

something.addEventListener('click', eventObject => {
  // Do something
}, false);
```

So as you can see, if a normal function is used, the variable `name` will contain the `Event` object instead of the actual name. Therefore by using curry function the function **RETURNED** by this will have the `Event` object passed down, ready to be used.

Answer (score 1):

`this.handleChange('name')` fired when init, returns a function and assigned to `onChange` function.

```
(event) => {
  this.setState({
    [name]: event.target.value
  })
}
```

Now, It's the same with

```
<TextField
    ...
    value={name}
    onChange={this.handleEvent}
/>
//[name] now become yourName. It's `closure`
handleEvent = (event) => this.setState({yourName: event.target.value})
```

And `event` now represent for the `TextField` when you fire the function.

Answer (score 1):

In react, event in this case is a synthetic event instance passed onto handler events. Read more of it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). This allows you to access the value on the event.target property. In this example, this handler event simply sets the state of whatever the value of name is with the value entered on the text field. Hope this clears it up!